# what java Design pattern to use for setting large number of member variables

Tags: java, design-patterns

Recently i faced one interview question.

> Question :Suppose you have many values (lets say more then 20) which
>   you need to set in object. now setting these values using setters or
>   using constructor is tedious task.

What java design pattern will you use to solve this problem

Help me know the solution guys.

Comment: Have you looked at any design patterns?

Comment: Take a look at the builder pattern: https://github.com/BrunoDM2943/PythonPatterns/tree/master/builder

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the end the attributes somehow, but some patterns might help you making it less chatty. A quick [wikipedia search for creational patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Creational_patterns) reveals some possible fits depending on the exact situation:

- Factory and Factory Method can take the attributes as parameters at once, for example.
- Builder generally makes it easier to construct an object fitted to your current needs.
- Prototype might help when you want to repeatedly create similar instances of a type.

To really decide, you need toknow the exact circumstances and needs.

Answer (score 1):

Standard builder:

```
public class Account {

  private final String userId;
  private final String token;

  public Account(String userId, String token) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.token = token;
  }

  public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
  }

  public String getToken() {
    return token;
  }

  public static class Builder {

    private String userId;
    private String token;

    public Builder setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;

        return this;
    }

    public Builder setToken(String token) {
        this.token = token;

        return this;
    }

    public Account build() {
        return new Account(userId, token);
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Both answers is correct. I showed to way to create builder. Difference in implementation : 
`Clazz.newBuilder().setI(0)./* .. */.build();` 
and
 `new Account.Builder().setUserId(userId)./* ... */.build();`

Answer (score 0):

If the values are heavily dynamic, what about having a `Map<String, Object>` (and maybe a `List<Object>` for index-based access) and methods like `public Double getDoubleByName(String nameKey)` (and the corresponding for index, like `public String getStringAt(int index)`)?
Edit:
If you are interesetd in a `Map` implementation that provides also an efficient (i.e.: *O(log2(n)*) way to access elements by their index like a `List`, then you could try to use my own `MapTreeAVL` available at [my repo](https://github.com/lonevetad/JavaBackups/tree/master/JavaBackup/AllProjects/src/dataStructures) with code like

```
MapTreeAVL<String, Object> m = MapTreeAVL.newMap(MapTreeAVL.Optimizations.ToQueueFIFOIterating, String::compareTo);
....
Object o = m.getAt(7);
```